# Get attribute in model - laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, getattribute

In laravel i can getFirstNameAttribute in my products model and change the value but I'm create this column "priceArray" and i can not get attributes because The first letter in the second word is capital letters and model can not found this column.

```
public function getPriceArrayAttribute($value)
    {
        return 'test';
    }
```

Its not work and can not get "priceArray" column

This is my migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->string('price')->nullable();
            $table->string('priceArray')->nullable();
            $table->text('items')->nullable();
            $table->enum('status',['active','inactive','unavailable'])->default('inactive');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

This is my product model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Class Products
 * @package App\Models
 * @property Variants Variants
 */
class Products extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded=[];
    protected $changePrice=0;

    public function Insert($data)
    {
        return self::create($data);
    }


    public function getPriceArrayAttribute($value)
    {
        return 'test';

    }

    public function getPriceAttribute($value)
    {

        return ceil($value);
    }


}
```

The getPriceAttribute is worked but getPriceArrayAttribute does not worked

Comment: This would work as `$model->price_array` or `$model->priceArray`; can you please include all relevant code, including where you try to use this? Also, if you have a `price_array` column, you'll need to name this something else to prevent ambiguity, like `getPriceArrayColAttribute`, then `$model->price_array_col` or `$model->priceArrayCol`

Comment: My column in table set priceArray and i need call the getPriceArrayAttribute function in my model and change the value for all of the rows

Comment: @TimLewis question was edited

Comment: Yup, so you have a `priceArray` column. When you call `$model->priceArray`, it is returning the value from the database. When you call `$model->price_array`, it should say `'test'`. Or you could follow my original comment and give them unique names. You still didn't include how you're using this code though... By design, this function doesn't really do anything until you call it. Honestly I'm just not sure what you're trying to do here 

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to modify the priceArray value after it is retrieved from the database, the way you did with ceil() on the price attribute. The only way this works is if you change the column name to price_array. This is by far the simplest fix.

**Migration**

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('title')->nullable();
    $table->string('price')->nullable();
    $table->string('price_array')->nullable();
    $table->text('items')->nullable();
    $table->enum('status',['active','inactive','unavailable'])->default('inactive');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Model**

```
public function getPriceArrayAttribute($value)
{
    return 'test';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must follow Eloquent's rules: you use **snake case** for the attributes. The `getPriceArrayAttribute` accessor will automatically be called by Eloquent when you retrieve the value of the `price_array`  attribute.

```
$table->string('price_array')->nullable();
```

Answer (score -1):

The value of the input argument should be set to the column name of the table you want to change,And you must separate the names of the tables with an underline

```
 /**
 * Summary of getIsActiveAttribute
 * @param mixed $is_active
 * @return string
 */
public function getIsActiveAttribute($is_active)
{
    return $is_active ? 'Active' : 'Deactive';
}
```

Comment: Get attribute method doesn't need to have an argument and the passed argument will not be processed while accessing the property.